# Problema al deployar function de firebase functions para enviar correo al cargar datos a firestore

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, firebase

estoy tratando de usar firebase functions en reactjs para crear un trigger que envíe un correo cuando se cargue información en la base de datos de firestore.

Se crea un puente con nodemailer y una función que se ejecuta el cargarse un nuevo documento en en l db.

Este es el código:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
/* const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(); */

// Gmail Account
const gmailUser = "myname@gmail.com"; //mail de ejemplo, uso otro
const gmailPassword = "mypass"; //pass de ejemplo, no es el real que uso.

const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: gmailUser,
    pass: gmailPassword
  }
});
exports.newContact = functions.firestore
  .document("/Contactos/{documentId}")
  .onCreate((snap, contenxt) => {
    const name = snap.data().name;
    return sendEmail(name);
  });

const sendEmail = (name) => {
  return transport
    .sendMail({
      from: gmailUser,
      to: "myEmail@gmail.com",
      subject: "test",
      html: name
    })
    .then(r => console.log(r))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

Hasta ahí todo bien. El problema ocurre cuando quiero deployar:
Ejecuto el comando: `firebase deploy --only functions`
y la consola me tira lo siguiente:

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        newContact(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

Un error más detallado sería el siguiente:

```
{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code.
```

Comment: A mi me ha sucedido algo similar, y pasa cuando el código tiene algun error... porque firebase no encuentra alguna librería que estas intentando usar o por que el código tiene algun error, ya intentaste correr esa funcion en tu maquina local? a ver si depronto te muestra mas claramente cual es el error? Por ejemplo corriendo: `firebase emulators:start --only functions`

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Si he corrido el emulador y esto es lo que me dice:   ```function ignored because the firestore emulator does not exist or is not running```

Comment: Y `firebase functions:shell`? Quizas aqui adivinando... Si pasas la definición de sendEmail antes de la de newContact?

Comment: Probé pasando sendEmail primero y no funcionó. Probé ```firebase functions:shell``` y dice esto: ```functions: Loaded functions: newContact
!  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services will affect production: firestore, database, pubsub, storage
firebase >
```